# SQL: SELECT if field has altitude and longitude values

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, psql

I have a address table as following:

```
         Column         |           Type           |                         Modifiers                          
------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                  | not null default nextval('venue_address_id_seq'::regclass)
 street                 | character varying        | not null
 number                 | character varying        | 
 zip                    | character varying        | 
 state                  | character varying        | 
 country                | character varying        | 
 location               | point                    | 
 venue_id               | integer                  | not null
 created_at             | timestamp with time zone | 
 created_by             | json                     | 
 updated_at             | timestamp with time zone | 
 updated_by             | json                     | 
 city_id                | integer                  | 
 name                   | character varying        | 
 district_id            | bigint                   | 
 deleted                | boolean                  | not null default false
 location_email         | character varying        | 
 participant_list_email | character varying        |
```

Street field in some rows has invalid data that needs to be corrected, these data are: altitude and longitude values.

As following

```
SELECT street from address where id=10;
```

Result:

```
 id |        street        
----+----------------------
  1 | Paseo de la Castellana, 75 (40°26'42.4"N 3°41'33.7"W)
  2 | Calle Anil, 21 (40.456744,-3.616466)
  3 | Correct address, 55
(2 rows)
```

I want to just keep the street name and number but remove altitude and longitude values, like the 3rd correct record

I am using postgres DBMS. My try was to find the wrong ones:

```
select id, street from venue_address WHERE street like '*(';
```

But I even do not know how to correct after getting the wrong ones.

**Q:** Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: PgSQL have native support of [regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)... You may try to use `~` operator instead of `LIKE`.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, a simple observation is that a correct address doesn't have parentheses.  If this is true in your data, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(address, ' [(].*[)]', '')
from t;
```

This just removes anything between parentheses.  If the format of the unwanted data is more consistent than that, you can revise the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
update address set street=regexp_replace(street, '[(].*[)]', '') where street ~ '[(].*[)]'
```